# how to get the current [pageSizeOptions] into component on click of other Button(not Pagination buttons)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular5, angular7

I am having a scenario where I want to get the current pageSizeOptions like 20 to display the data where [pageSizeOptions] = {10,20,30,40,50};

The user has already selected the pageSizeOption as 20 and when he clicks on other button(other than Pagination), the pageSigeOption shows 20, but i get only 10 records.This is happening because Whenever I am clicking on the button.
I am calling the paginate method with page event as 0 and pageSize as 10 and utilizing it in my Paginate method.

I want to set the pageSize event as whatever is selected in the pageSizeOption as for example 20 and when I selected on the other button, the same pageSize to be passed to the Paginate method(without clicking on the Pagination item).

Comment: stackblitz please

Answer (score 0):

the issue got resolved by using in the code.
**this.paginator.pageSize**